# a confusion on rsync

Tags: rsync

have to make incremental backups with rsync and dropbox. The simple scenario is like this

Say I have some directories under my home directory, like

```
   Python
   MATLAB
   C++
   LaTeX
   ANSYS
```

and under them, I have files with extensions

```
.py for python
.m  for MATLAB
.cc for C++
.tex for LaTeX
.inp or .mac for ANSYS
```

I would like to backup these directories and only the files with the specified extensions under these directories. I am reading the rsync documentation, so for extensions it is possible to create a file, say 'extensions', and use `--include-from=extensions`.

I also read about the `--files-from=FILE` option, first I thought of creating a another file with the directories to be used in the backup and use the `--no-relative` option(since `--relative` is the default), however this is not working

What is the mistake in this reasoning? or what could be a better way to accomplish the above scenario?

Comment: Those are all source code files. If you put them in a version control system (Mercurial or git is really easy to start with) and push changes to a remote repo (that is being backed up or mirrored again), then you don't really need another backup scheme.

Comment: well, I am using git already, but just could not understand how to do this with rsync, most probably there is a misunderstanding...

Comment: maybe this is helpful then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-git-and-dropbox-together-effectively?lq=1

Comment: What is the `rsync` command you are trying? What result are you getting? How is it not working?